# Parquet troubles with decimal in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

Since 3 or 4 days i'm experiencing troubles in writing decimal values in parquet file format with Azure Data Factory V2.

The repro steps are quite simple, from an SQL source containing a numeric value i map it to a parquet file using the copy activity.

At runtime the following exception is thrown:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorParquetTypeNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Decimal Precision or Scale information is not found in schema for column: ADDRESSLONGITUDE,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.ParquetTransferPlugin,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.,Source=mscorlib,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Data"
}
```

In the source the complaining column is defined as numeric(32,6) type.

I think the problem is circumscribed to the parquet sink because changing the destination format to csv result in a succeeded pipeline.

Any suggestions?

Based on Jay's answer, here is the whole dataset :

```
SELECT 
    [ADDRESSLATITUDE]
FROM 
    [dbo].[MyTable]
```

[image: query result]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [SQL Types to Parquet Logical Types](https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-format/#sql-types-to-parquet-logical-types) and [Data type mapping for Parquet files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#data-type-mapping-for-parquet-files) in data factory copy activity,it supports `Decimal` data type.Decimal data is converted into binary data type.

[image]

Back to your error message:

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
>   ErrorCode=UserErrorParquetTypeNotSupported,
>     'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
>     Message=Decimal Precision or Scale information is not found in schema
>   for column: 
>     ADDRESSLONGITUDE,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.ParquetTransferPlugin,''
>     Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object cannot be cast from
>   DBNull to other types.,Source=mscorlib,'

If your numeric data has `null` value, it will be converted into `Int` data type without any 
Decimal precision or scale information.

[image]

Csv format does not have this transformation process so you could set default value for your numeric data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jay. Would that mean that nullable decimal isn't supported? nahh.. can't believe that!!

Comment: @FabriceMichellonet Could you just extract several sample data to do the same test ?

Comment: Furtermore, in my example there are no null values. SELECT [ADDRESSLATITUDE] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]  returns 3 non null lines, exact value are 0.000000.

Comment: @FabriceMichellonet Trying to reproduce your issue,any progress will be updated in my answer.Thanks.